# Differential of distance-squared on Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

**Problem:**

Let $\mathcal{M}_1$ and $\mathcal{M}_2$ be two Riemannian manifolds. Function $g:\mathcal{M}_1\to\mathcal{M}_2$ is a smooth mapping. $\theta(t)$ and $\gamma(t)$ are two curves on $\mathcal{M}_1$ and $\mathcal{M}_2$ respectively. The Riemannian distance is denoted by $d(\cdot,\cdot)$.

I would like to know what $\frac{d}{dt} [d(g(\theta(t)),\gamma(t))]^2$ is.

**My attempt:**

Assuming the inverse of the *exponential mapping*, denoted by $\text{Exp}^{-1}$, is well-defined globally. The *parallel transport* is denoted by $\Gamma$. Then
\begin{align}
&\frac{d}{dt} [d(g(\theta(t)),\gamma(t))]^2 \\
=& \frac{d}{dt} \langle\text{Exp}^{-1}_{\gamma(t)}g(\theta(t)),\text{Exp}^{-1}_{\gamma(t)}g(\theta(t))\rangle_{\gamma(t)}\\
=&2 \langle \text{Exp}^{-1}_{\gamma(t)}g(\theta(t)), \Gamma_{g(\theta(t))}^{\gamma(t)} \text{D}g(\theta(t))[\dot{\theta}(t)]-\dot{\gamma}(t)\rangle_{\gamma(t)}
\end{align}

**Questions:**

I assume the first equality will hold under some general conditions on $\text{Exp}^{-1}$ and the specific manifold structure.

The second equality is my conjecture. I appreciate if you could help me check its correctness.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not just compute this first for 2 curves $\eta, \gamma$ in $\mathcal{M}_2$? After that, you can replace all of the $\eta$s by $g\circ\theta$.

Comment: Hi Deane. Thank you for your comment. But I am still unclear how to compute for 2 curves. Do you have any recommendations for references?

Answer (score 1):

I dislike working with the exponential map directly. I suggest doing the following: Given the two curves $c_0(t)$ and $c_1(t)$ on a manifold $M$, where $0 \le t \le T$, define $C: [0,T]\times[0,1] \rightarrow M$ such that the following hold:
\begin{align*}
C(t,0) &= c_0(t)\\
C(t,1) &= c_1(t)
\end{align*}
and, for each $t \in [0,T]$, the curve $C(t,\cdot)$ is a constant speed length-minimizing geodesic from $c_0(t)$ to $c_1(t)$.

Note that for each $t \in [0,T]$, $|\partial_sC(t,s)| = d(c_0(t),c_1(t))$ and therefore, for any $s \in [0,1]$,
$$ \frac{d}{dt}g(c_0(t),c_1(t)) = \frac{d}{dt}g(\partial_sC(t,s),\partial_sC(s,t)).$$
Also, note that the vector field $\partial_tC$ is a Jacobi field along the geodesic $C(t,\cdot)$. Also, note that the only thing you care about is the length of the tangential component of the Jacobi field.

I suggest doing some calculations with this and see what you can figure out from them.